# Cannot use theme omega after upgrading from Primefaces 8 to Primefaces 10

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I tried to upgrade from PrimeFaces 8 to PrimeFaces 10.
Everything works fine but I have an error with omega theme :

```
Grave:   Error Rendering View[/public/main_page.xhtml]
javax.faces.FacesException: Error loading CSS, cannot find "theme.css" resource of "primefaces-omega" library
```

This is web.xml :

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
    <param-value>omega</param-value>
</context-param>
```

If I change PrimeFaces version to 8.0, it works fine :

```
    // This doesn't work
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
        <version>10.0.0-RC2</version>
    </dependency>

    // This works
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
        <version>8.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Do I miss something ?

Comment: https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/10_0_0/#/../migrationguide/10_0_0

Comment: Ok thank you, I'm confused because it's listed here : https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/10_0_0/#/core/themes

Comment: fixed the docs now ;D